# video snapshot generating horizontally in node js.

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg

I am using FFMPEG for generating snapshot of video but problem is that snapshot is capturing horizontally i want it to vertical.

**code**

```
pathToFile = path+name;
        pathToSnapshot = path+'sshot.jpg';

          // Also a default node module

          require('child_process').exec(('ffmpeg -i '+ pathToFile +' -vframes 1 -s 450x450 -ss 02 '+ pathToSnapshot), function () {});
```

Comment: If you mean to rotate, add `-vf transpose=1` or `2` to rotate it clockwise or counter-clockwise respectively.

Comment: where to use? can you say me with applied code?

Comment: Try `require('child_process').exec(('ffmpeg -i '+ pathToFile +' -vf transpose=1 -vframes 1 -s 450x450 -ss 02 '+ pathToSnapshot), function () {});`

Comment: thanks , working..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
require('child_process').exec(('ffmpeg -i '+ pathToFile +' -vf transpose=1 -vframes 1 -s 450x450 -ss 02 '+ pathToSnapshot), function () {});
```

This will rotate the video clockwise. Use `transpose=2` to rotate it counter clockwise.